# Can't access response from API properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My API returns this `response`:

```
{"__v":0,"short":"8xdn4a5k","_id":"5404db5ac27408f20440babd","branches":[{"version":1,"code":""}],"ext":"js","language":"javascript"}
```

This works:

```
console.log(response.short);
```

but this produces `undefined`:

```
console.log(response.branches.version);
```

How come?

Comment: branches is an array, try `response.branches[0].version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `branches` property of `response` is an array:

```
"branches":[{"version":1,"code":""}]
```

So, you have to access the first element of `branches` (which is the object you're looking for) to get the `version` property:

```
response.branches[0].version
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, **branches** has no nodes that can be reach by it's name, only an array, so you can't get it by a name (which doesn't have) , you'll have to do:

```
console.log(response.branches[0].version);
```

---

*Indexed* and *Associative* arrays are  different.